# Is it possible to dynamically create swagger specs by namespace?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I would like to create swagger specs, grouped by namespace in my mvc application.

For example, if i have the following api controllers:

```
- Portal.Example1.Sub1
- Portal.Example1.Sub2
- Portal.Example2.Section2
- Portal.Example2.Section4
- Portal.Example3.Something4
- Portal.Example3.Whatever69
```

I would like the output swagger-ui page to create a spec for `Example1` with all the actions in `Sub1` and `Sub2`, etc...

Currently, my code is setup as so:

In `Startup:ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Portal API", Version = "v1" });
    options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);
    options.EnableAnnotations();
});
```

In `Startup:Configure`

```
app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Portal API V1");
    options.IndexStream = () => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Portal.Web.wwwroot.swagger.ui.index.html");
    options.InjectBaseUrl(""http://localhost:62114/");
}); //URL: /swagger
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i have done this with spring creating classes of this kind:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;

@Api(value = "categoryA", description = "categoryA Managent")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/categoryA")
public class CategoryA {
...
}
```

When i look in my code, it works with one package. If you get problems you maybe need to change it in a way it looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"Portal.controller", "Portal.AllExamples"}) 
public class Application {

    @Value("${info.app.version:unknown}") String version;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(Portal.AllExamples.class.getPackage().getName()))
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*")).build().apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
    }

    public ApiInfo apiEndPointsInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("My REST API").description("bla bla bla.")
                .contact(new Contact("yourcorp", "yoururl", "you@mail"))
                .license("free for all license").licenseUrl("https://free.beer.org").version(version)
                .build();
    }
```

...

Comment: That looks like angular, im trying to do this in asp.net core (c#) and regular html/js

Comment: no, it is java. but i hope it help anyway. If you feel it doesn't i can delete it .

Comment: the class names look similar, so im trying to translate it now. id say leave it.